# Error in extension installing-opencart2

Tags: php, opencart2.x

When i'm installing the extension it gives the following error.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
>
> OK
>
> **Warning**:  POST Content-Length of 12255610 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in **Unknown** on line **0**
>   {"error":"File could not be uploaded!"}

Please help me to fix this error.Thank You in advance.

Comment: increase your [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) to be larger than 8MB, actually 12255610 maybe wrap into 12 MB ,so you may make it 20 or 18.

Answer (score 0):

I made following changes in php.ini file

1.max_input_time=120

2.memory_limit=256M

3.post_max_size=64M

4.upload_max_filesize=64M

after save these changes please start Apache.

My error now fixed.Thank You.